# Wasting cycles with actual arbitrary instructions with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, cpu, cpu-usage, instructions

I have been working on a project in which I need to create a Python application that wastes instructions & cycles at this stage. Normally when 'cycle wasting' means waiting or sleeping; but I want to do it in a different manner. There should be some dummy instructions which wastes cycles even though the iteration period of the outer program loop is pretty high.

As an example (typical way to do it):

```
while(True):
    #..do simple thing..
    time.sleep(0.000001)
```

What I want to do:

```
while(True):
    #..do complex instructions..
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

With the first 'typical' example I am able to achieve custom CPU loads such as 25% or 100% by simply adjusting the sleeping period. I want to be able to do the same with the second code, where the period is a pretty high value and is constant, but the instructions are complex and dynamic.

Please keep in mind that I have to do this as  a Python application and not as a bash script that runs from shell.

Is there a way to achieve this? Any help will be greately appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

**Note:** I apologize if there is a wrong tag.

**Edit:** Using Python 2.7

**Edit:** The application requires that there should be a periodic sleep, such as time.sleep(2), time.sleep(0.2). This is kind of our restriction.

Comment: Which python version is this? 2.7 or 3.x?

Comment: Hi, I'm using Python 2.7 on Linux

Comment: matrix multiplications are pretty cpu-intensive, maybe you can generate two random matrices of varying sizes and multiply them?

Comment: or, consider donating the `wasted-cycles` to SETI or another public distributed computing project instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't think about the best way, just tried something, its 100% CPU on my laptop i5.
I go for random matrix generation and product:

```
def cpu_load():
    import numpy as np
    while True:
    a = np.random.random([1000, 1000])
    b = np.random.random([1000, 1000])
    c = np.mean(a*b)
```

Comment: Can you add a time.sleep(0.2) below and try again. Because when there is no delay, it is obviously going to be 100%.

Comment: I don't really get your point. How could a code with sleep even approach 100% load? What do you want the load to be?

Comment: I dont want it to exactly reach 100%, but at least can be like 50%.
If you put print "hello" without sleep, that also will go to 100%. That is not what I wanted.

Comment: Then I would go for my solution and use `nice` as suggested below. Anyway it does sound super weird

Comment: I will try those at the office and get back. Thanks for suggestion

Comment: This did the work with various sleeps between 1 and 0.01. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, and building further upon the code by [pltrdy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5903959/pltrdy), I think you want something like this:

```
def cpu_load(treshold):
    import numpy as np
    import time
    start = time.time()
    while time.time() - start < treshold:
        a = np.random.random([1000, 1000])
        b = np.random.random([1000, 1000])
        c = np.mean(a*b)
```

Comment: I will try this soon. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

If you are on a Linux system, you can do this.

```
import os
os.nice(20)
```

This will increase the niceness of the process. Therefore reducing CPU consumption.

[Here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.nice) is the documentation.